# Android - System cancel my alarms, without my permission

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I created a android app, in short the app just create some alarms for the day.
All the alarms are created at the same time. When I kill the app from the shell, the alarms are still here, obviously when I force kill the app the alarms is cancelled.

How I create one alarm :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent alarmPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, alarmId, intent, 0);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTimeInMillis(), alarmPendingIntent);
```

And my Manifest :

```
    ...
    <receiver
        android:name=".schedule.AlarmReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" />
    ...
```

The problem is : **my android system cancel all my alarms without visible problem...**

I make some test and even if the app is open the system cancel my alarms, not systematically, but sometimes...

So, what reasons could cancel the alarms of my app, force kill exclude ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you checked that `.schedule.AlarmReceiver` is really not receiving all alarm broadcasts? It could be the case that it does get triggered, but then the receiver get's killed immediately because of some not-in-foreground/permission issues. Also, what API version are you targeting and on what API version are executing your code?

Comment: Then there's also the Doze mode and App Standby issue, but that should only delay the alarm, not remove it completely.

Comment: Yes `.schedule.AlarmReceiver` receive all alarm broadcasts. I check it with a simple test : function create all my alarms, and a another function check if the alarms exist (create same intent and execute `PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, intentId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null` return `true` if the alarm is up).The first time the check function return all alarms are up, but sometimes after all alarms are cancelled... Targeting API : 25, executing API 26, min API 16

Comment: What device are you testing this on?

Comment: How do you know the alarms are canceled by Android? You can get a list of pending alarms by using `adb shell dumpsys alarm`

Comment: One Plus 3, Android 8.0.0 API 26. Like I said, to know if my alarms are canceled I have function which just recreated the same Intent and try to create the same broadcast with flag FLAG_NO_CREATE (see previous comment). The consequences if alarms are canceled are that my device doesn't show the notification (even if I change the hour and date of my device) and my check function returns that all my alarms are canceled..